# French Mutuelle when both spouses are working

Tags: france, social-security

Uptil now my wife was not working and she and my son are on my mutuelle (I work in the private sector). However, when she starts working in the private sector will she necessarily be dropped from my mutuelle? If so what happens to our son? Whose mutuelle will he be on?

Answer (score 3):

Based on personal experience in France :

Theoretically, your wife may decline the mandatory *mutuelle* from her employer based on the fact that she is already covered by your own mandatory *mutuelle*. **Notice that the request has to be explicitly done at the time of entering the new company**. She might be asked to prove that she is already covered by producing an *attestation* from your current *mutuelle*.

(See [Peut-on refuser la mutuelle ou la prévoyance de son entreprise ?](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F20740), *Vous avez déjà une mutuelle en tant qu'ayant droit (couverture collective)*).

Employers are sometime reluctant to apply this rule.

In any case, your wife and son stay covered by your own *mutuelle* as long as you keep subscribing to your own employer's *mutuelle* family option.

*edit*

Is it possible to subscribe later if one has declined the subscription at the beginning of their contract ? Probably yes but that has to be checked with one's employer.

*/edit*

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. What happens in case I then loose my job or switch jobs 

To be precise I am about to begin a rupture conventionelle and that would allow me to be on my soon to be ex-companie's mutuelle for a year. However, I am also going to start working with another company in a couple of months and would then, presumably, be forced to be on the new companies mutuelle and then we may have a choice on which one is better.

Comment: Sorry, I don't feel like I can give simple advice on a complex case with high stakes. You should try to get personalized advice given you and your wife's actual situation (Is there an _assistante sociale_ at your current workplace ?). One thing is to keep in mind : one can only refuse mandatory _mutuelle_ when beginning their contract and having proof of coverage by another mean.

Comment: I understand. I guess my question is simpler than it looks. While one can only refuse mandatory mutuelle in the beginning, can they join it later when the situation changes and they loose the alternate mutuelle?

Comment: I would say yes but one should check with it's employer.